# Gain of implement our Spring event listener

Tags: java, spring, events, listener

Studying about Spring event handlers i cannot see what is the gain ou benefits of implement our event listener, I mean, What is the difference in Object A calling object B directly synchronously ou Object A, using one Listener and one EventHandler, publishing and then the Object B be called. may be is about some architecture gain or to get low coupling ? which is the real gain? tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned this approach lowers the coupling between classes as the sender or receiver of the event don't know about each other.

Just in case, it's not ideal to use this approach for *all* method invocations, but it makes a lot of sense when the operations are not really related.

For example, imagine the following scenario: *When a user completes his registration, we'll send him/her a welcome email*.

In this case, coupling the registration process to sending the email is not great. But if you have a listener on the *UserRegistered* event, then the email can be triggered out of that event. I really like this way of build applications as it makes them more decoupled, but, depending what event dispatcher you use, it becomes more difficult to understand the flow (e.g. if the event dispatcher receives a string as the event name and a map with the data, then is difficult to easily get a list of all consumers).

One important aspect (or I should say smell) is that 2 listeners that are listening for the same event shouldn't depend on the order they consume the event. This applies to all event dispatchers, not just the one implemented by Spring.